# Halmos: Principle of induction shows only one function satisfies a recurrence relation.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction, set-theory

> Induction is often used not only to prove things but also to define things.
> Suppose, to be specific, that $f$ is a function from a set $X$ into the same set
> $X$, and suppose that $a$ is an element of $X$. It seems natural to try to define
> an infinite sequence $\{u(n)\}$ of elements of $X$ (that is, a function $u$ from $\omega \to X$) in some such way as this: write $u(0) = a, u(1) = f(u(0)), u(2) = f(u(1))$, and so on. If the would-be definer were pressed to explain the "and so on," he might lean on induction. What it all means, he might say, is that we define $u(0)$ as $a$, and then, inductively, we define $u(n^{+})$ as $f(u(n))$ for every $n$. This may sound plausible, but, as justification for an existential assertion, it is insufficient. **The principle of mathematical induction does indeed prove, easily, that there can be at most one function satisfying all the stated conditions**, but it does not establish the existence of such a function.

(Book: Halmos, Paul. *Naive Set Theory*, Section 12, The Peano Axioms, p.48.)

What might Halmos mean by the line in bold? What is the proof in question? I feel like I am missing something obvious.

Context:

The set of natural numbers is denoted $\omega$ here.

The successor of $n$ is $n^{+}$ here.

Principle of induction is expressed set-theoretically as $$ S\subseteq \omega \wedge 0\in S \wedge (n\in S \Rightarrow n^{+} \in S) \Rightarrow S = \omega$$

Comment: By induction, if two sequences match up to some value then they match at the next (since the next is determined by a set function of the prior values).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose two such functions $u_1$ and $u_2$ exist and they’re not equal.  Then the set $A=\{ n \in \Bbb N \mid u_1(n) \neq u_2(n) \}$ is a non-empty set of natural numbers, so it must have a least element.  What can that least element be?

It can’t be $0$ because we’re given that $u_1(0)=a=u_2(0)$.  Therefore, the least element of $A$ must take the form $m+1$ for some $m$.

But that’s not possible either.  Since $m+1$ is the least element where $u_1$ and $u_2$ differ, $m \lt m+1$ tells us that $u_1(m)=u_2(m)$.  But then $u_1(m+1)=f(u_1(m))=f(u_2(m))=u_2(m+1)$ and, contrary to our assumption, $m+1 \notin A$ after all.

This contradiction shows that $A$ can’t have a least element, so it must be empty; in other words, $\forall n \in \Bbb N ~ (u_1(n)=u_2(n))$.

Answer (score 3):

Once you prove the existence of such a function u you can prove its uniqueness under these conditions using induction.

Suppose that $v$ is another function from $\omega$ to $X$ verifying $v(0)=a$ and $v(n^+)=f(v(n))$. Now let S be the set of all natural numbers on which $u$ & $v$ agree. Since $u(0)=v(0)=a$, $0\in S$. Now suppose that $n\in S$, i.e. $u(n)=v(n)$. Then $u(n^+)=f(u(n))=f(v(n))=v(n^+)$ where the second equality is by our induction hypothesis and the other two are by the conditions satified by $u$ and $v$. Therefore, by induction, $S=\omega$  and hence $u$ is unique under these conditions.

So what Halmos meant is that the recursion theorem states the "existence" and "uniqueness" of such a function. The existence part, as you can see in his book, is given as the intersection of the collection of ordered pairs in $\omega \times X$ with the desired properties and not by induction. However, the uniqueness part is proved by induction.